# undefined reference to `boost::thread

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, boost

I am trying to link libgetfiles.so to main.cpp. I ran the following command:

`sudo g++ main.cpp -L/ubuntu/test -lgetfiles -L/usr/local/lib/ -lboost_thread`

It gives me the following error:

`/ubuntu/test/libgetfiles.so: undefined reference to'boost::thread::start_thread_noexcept()'
/ubuntu/test/libgetfiles.so: undefined reference to 'boost::thread::join_noexcept()'
/ubuntu/test/libgetfiles.so: undefined reference to 'boost::system::system_category()'
/ubuntu/test/libgetfiles.so: undefined reference to 'boost::system::generic_category()'`

How can I resolve them?

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling boost libraries as well.
I have also tried the below command:

`g++ main.cpp -L/ubuntu/test -lgetfiles -L/usr/local/lib/ -lboost_thread-mt`

Both of them did not work for me.

Comment: are you sure you've got the lib in /usr/local/lib/?

Comment: You should probably also add `-lboost_system` to linker flags.

Comment: @ Zereges Thanks  Zereges.
That reduced boost::system errors but I still have boost::thread errors

Comment: @ Oleksandr Kravchuk I used sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev command to install boost. So how to check where all packages are installed?

Answer (score 0):

If you manually build and install boost (i.e. specific version), you should check you already not have *libboost-all-dev* package installed inside */usr/lib*. Try to `rm /usr/lib/libboost* && rm -r /usr/include/boost` and then build again.